# Angular: How I can test @HostListener in jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the next code in angular's component:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', []) onWindowScroll() {
  this.showScrollToTop = false;
}
```

How can I test this in jasmine? How to to initiate window scroll event?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Testing for window:scroll:

```
it('should do something on window scroll', () => {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
  expect(...)....
});
```

Comment: But how can I specify the amount to scroll?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make simple JS scroll by calling `scrollTo` function on window.

In case you want to make scroll top it will be:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

**Update**

```
var scrollEvent = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
scrollEvent.initCustomEvent( 'scroll', false, false, null );

window.dispatchEvent(scrollEvent)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But unfortunately, this doesn't trigger 'onWindowScroll'

Comment: Could you try to make a custom event with `scroll` name? updating my answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
 it('Focus over elements', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const event = new Event('click', { bubbles: true });
    const spyDocumentClick = spyOn(component, 'clickout').and.callThrough();
    component.clickout(event);
    expect(spyDocumentClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```